# How to make the "update" function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am very new to RoR. I started to make the registration of user the login, showing and deleting, but i cant make the EDIT/UPDATE function. I am going to post my register function and my html form that i used for register and i want the same to use for EDIT/UPDATE.

The register function

```
def register
@name = params[:name]
@surname = params[:surname]
@username = params[:username]
@password = params[:password]
@email = params[:email]
@tel = params[:tel]
@role_id = params[:role_id]
user = User.create_with_password(@name,@surname,@username,@email,@password,@tel,@role_id)
if user
  #session[:signed_in] = true
  session[:username] = user.username
  redirect_to "/menaxhimi_pushimit/index"
else
  redirect_to "/menaxhimi_pushimit/index"
end
```

end

User model

```
    def self.create_with_password(name, surname, username, email, password, tel, role_id)
    salt = SecureRandom.hex
    password_hash = self.generate_hash(password, salt)

    self.create(
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        salt: salt,
        password_hash: password_hash,
        tel: tel,
        role_id: role_id
        )
end 

def verify_password(password)
    self.password_hash == User.generate_hash(password, self.salt)
end

def self.generate_hash(password, salt)
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
digest.update(password)
digest.update(salt)
digest.to_s
end
```

end

My html form

```
      <form action='/menaxhimi_pushimit/update' class='validate-form' method='post'>
    <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" required />
    <input type="surname" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" required />
    <input type="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" required />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Tel" name="tel" required />
    <input type="Roli" placeholder="Roli" name="role_id" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
  </form>
```

Can somebody help how to modify the register for EDIT/UPDATE

Thanks in advance

Comment: check your form action in the html file, change the action to register

Comment: it doest work like that, it doesnt update it instead it creates new user. register and update are the same

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit using rails is its conventions if you use them u don't have to write your own custom code. you need to google and learn basic CRUD operations using rails-4.

Here is a link of [Demo](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) User authentication app u can follow this code and make your own.

Comment: i dont want to make this from the begining, it would cost me a lot of time.

Comment: then sorry brother i cant help you u are not even using ruby on rails. Form u created is not in a Rails way. If you want to learn things right then read some content on google then use it. best of luck